# How do I pass arguments to my functions in a zsh/bash script?

Tags: bash, encryption, sh, getopts

I am trying to combine these two functions in a script. The idea is to pass the flags -E to encrypt, and -D to decrypt. So far the flags are working. I get the different usages for encrypt, decrypt and help.
Problem: The functions aren't getting the arguments and I get the usage message every time.
How do I pass the arguments to the functions?
e.g.:

```sh
./cript.zsh -E filetoencript out.des3
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

# TODO, make it a script. Flags -E to encrypt -D to decrypt.
# Usage: $1 = input $2 = output
function encrypt() {
  if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo Usage: encrypt '<infile>' '[outfile]'
    return
  fi
  if [ -z "$2" ]; then
    out="$1".des3
  else
   
...

}

# Usage: $1 = input $2 = output
function decrypt() {
  if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo Usage: decrypt '<infile>' '[outfile]'
    return
  fi
  if [ -z "$2" ]; then
    
...

}

function main() {
# -E = encrypt
# -D = decrypt
# FIXME
while getopts ":E:D:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    E)
        encrypt
        ;;
    D)
        decrypt
        ;;
    *)
        help
        exit 1
        ;;
  esac
done
}

main "$@"
```

Comment: Please remove `bash` or `zsh` tag.

Comment: `shift; encrypt "$@"`

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035

Comment: Each function has its *own* set of positional parameters; `$1` in a function refers to the first argument of the *function*, not the first argument of the script. You have to explicitly pass script arguments to the function when you call it.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. @jordanm answer solved my problem right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
function main() {
# -E = encrypt
# -D = decrypt
while getopts ":E:D:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    E)
        shift
        encrypt "$@"
        ;;
    D)
        shift
        decrypt "$@"
        ;;
    *)
        help
        exit 1
        ;;
  esac
done
}
```